# What are the benefits of using built in functions with cb in js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, performance

I'm talking about array built-in functions mostly, like **reduce**, **map** etc.
The only advantage I see is that you can chain them.

Let's say you need to compute the sum of the elements in array.

```
const array = [1, 2, 3];
```

Is there any other benefit (besides the possibility to chain different methods) in using

```
const sum = array.reduce((prev, next) => prev + next, 0)
```

rather than

```
let sum = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) sum += array[i];
```

?

Comment: ease of use, nothing else. They have the disadvantage that you cant break inside of them so you always have to iterate all elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the built-in functions (reduce, map) etc. helps you or kind of force you to be write your code more in functional approach.
Basically, the `reduce` function also uses loop to prepare your desired result but every built-in function has different purpose.
On the other hand, loop is generic. It can be used to get any result.

[This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) is the list of all array methods and you will find that every method has its own purpose.

One of the big advantages of using the built-in ones is reusability.